# Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'List<DataTable>'

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a method in my code:

```
private void SetSubReportDataSource(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument document, List<DataTable> tables, int counter)
        {
            if (tables.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Data.DataSet reportDataSet = AddTableInReportDataSet(tables);

                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument subReport = document.Subreports[counter];
                subReport.SetDataSource(reportDataSet);
            }
        }
```

And I made this:

```
public List<DataTable> FillSubreport()
        {
            List<DataTable> ldt = new List<DataTable>();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SectionID");
            dt.Columns.Add("SectionName");

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "Subreport1"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "Subreport1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", "Subreport1" });

            ldt.Add(dt);
            return ldt;
        }
```

And when trying to make execute the first method like this:

```
SetSubReportDataSource(document, FillSubreport , subReportCounter);
```

FillSubreport is highlighed and I am getting this error:

```
Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'List<DataTable>'
```

Comment: In some cases, like `int arg = FillSubreport;` the compiler says: "error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'FillSubreport' to non-delegate type 'int'. __Did you intend to invoke the method?__" But this last suggestion is unfortunately not a part of the error text in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this also,

```
List<DataTable> data = FillSubreport(); 

SetSubReportDataSource(document, data , subReportCounter);
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a simple syntax error in your code:

```
SetSubReportDataSource(document, FillSubreport , subReportCounter);
```

You are attempting to call `FillSubreport` but you have failed to add `()` to the end of it to indicate it is a method.  Try:

```
SetSubReportDataSource(document, FillSubreport(), subReportCounter);
```